# OpenCV Train Cascade: VecSize not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

I've been trying to trade train a cascading classifier to recognize a blue 'X' on a white sheet of paper. The images (both positives and negatives) are JPGs, and in order to generate the necessary samples I used the perl script created by Naotoshi Seo.

The sample creation commands:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("perl createsamples.pl positives.txt negatives.txt " + output_dir + " " + str(num_pos_samples) + " opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 -maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 80 -h 45", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
proc.kill()
```

However, I run into an issue once I try and feed the merged vec file into the CascadeTrainer. I run

```
opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlamRate 0.5 -numPos 1300 -numNeg 1180 -w 80 -h 45 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 2048
```

and get an output of

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: classifier
vecFileName: samples.vec
bgFileName: negatives.txt
numPos: 1300
numNeg: 1180
numStages: 10
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 2048
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 2048
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 80
sampleHeight: 45
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.9999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.3
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: ALL
Number of unique features given windowSize [80,45] : 9969357

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_img.rows * _img.cols == vecSize) in 
CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::get, file C:\tools\opencv-
3.4.0\apps\traincascade\imagestorage.cpp, line 153
samples.vec created with 1300 positive samples and 1180 negative samples.
```

Now, obviously this is because the width and height of my image don't multiply to vecSize. However, I find this very strange: I recompiled the C++ code that trains the classifier to print out vecSize, and it's 576 (24*24) regardless of what I put in for 'width' and 'height' during the sample generation process.

In fact, if I set the width and height to each be 24, I get no errors. I can ue the perl script with widthxheight = 80x45, and then put in 24x24 for training with no issue. I find this strange because, looking at tutorials on how to train a Haar classifier, it doesn't seem as if the 'width' and 'height' parameters should matter in this way: it seems common to use values besides 24x24, or whatever else multiplies out to 576.

Why is vecSize this value? How can I change it so that I can use the 'width' and 'height' values I want to?

Comment: show your sample creation commands please

Comment: @Micka I added the sample creation commands. Sorry, I should have had those in from the start.